# Как получить названия файла из формы его загрузки

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Итак, у меня есть форма:
`<input type="file" name="image-comp" class="png-name">`
Мне нужно получить название файла из данной формы, чтобы добавить в базу данных.

Comment: На php, Вы сможете получить его только отправив данные form. А получить сможете его в `$_FILES['image-comp']`

Comment: Насколько понятно из вопроса, вы не представляете логику работы формы при загрузке файлов на сервер. Рекомендую почитать как отправлять(загружать) файлы на сервер... https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php